# IJW C# to MC++ to C++ transfer array of strings to char**

Tags: c++-cli

Does anyone know how to pin the following string array parameter:

```
function signature int TestMethod(int argc, array<String^>^ data)
{
   pin_ptr<char> p1 = &data[0];
   char** p2 = &p1[0];
   // char** argv = (char**)calloc(argc+1, sizeof(char*));
}
```

I want to pin an `array<String^>^` object and convert it to the following:

```
char** argv = (char**)calloc(argc+1, sizeof(char*));
```

so I can pass it to a native c++ function

any ideas?

What about the following?

UPDATE: just curious? what about the following?

```
char** argv = (char**)calloc(argc+1, sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < data->Length; i++)
{
            argv[i] =           (char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(data[i]).ToPointer();
}

// Use argv as needed here...
// Cleanup
for (int i = 0; i < data->Length; i++)
{
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)argv[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly pin a managed `String^` into a `char*`.  .NET Strings are actually 2 bytes per character, so you need to marshal the data manually.  This will likely require building up the character arrays, copying data into them, then cleaning up after you're done.

In this case, you likely need to copy the data into your `char**`, use it, then clean up after yourself.  This can be done via something like:

```
// Requires  #include <msclr\marshal.h> 
marshal_context context;

char** argv = new char*[data->Length];

for (int i=0;i<Length;++i)
{
    const char* tmp = context.marshal_as<const char*>(clrString);
    int length = strlen(tmp);
    argv[i] = new char[length+1]();
    strncpy(argv[i],tmp,length);
}

// Use argv as needed here...

// Cleanup
for (int i=0;i<Length;++i)
    delete[] argv[i];
delete[] argv;
```

Comment: A clarification: `marshal_context` is what controls the lifetime of the `const char*` returned by the `marshal_as` call.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Yes, which is why you don't have to release that memory.

Comment: For some reason "marshal_context" is reported as unidentified even in though I am resolving the "#include <msclr\marshal.h> " fine hm....

Comment: @JoeVolcano See req. headers here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384854.aspx